# How can I get my Material Design Icon Fonts to display properly?

Tags: html, css, icons, material-design

I'm struggling try to figure it out my icons doesn't display.

I have include the path to it like this

```
<link href="material/vendors/material-icons/material-design-iconic-font.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

This is my result

[image]

This is what I wish to achieve

[image]

This is everything in my my folder

[image]

Can someone please tell me what did I do wrong here ?

---

## Update

HTML

```
<ul class="main-menu">
    <li class="active"><a href="/"><i class="md md-home"></i> Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/web-directory"><i class="md md-format-underline"></i> Web Directory </a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: did you include the iconic font package in your project folder?

Comment: I updated my post to show you guys everything inside my folder.

Comment: What is font-package ? How do I get it ?

Comment: Are you sure that `material/vendors/material-icons/material-design-iconic-font.min.css` is the right path to the `material-design-iconic-font.min.css` file in respect to where the html file is?

Comment: yes. I'm sure. Thanks for checking. Any other suggestions - you may have ?

Comment: Can you post the html code where you're trying to get the icons?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79795/discussion-between-tiffany-soun-and-mark).

Comment: @Mark : Do you see my update ?

Comment: Judging by what you've posted it really looks like you didn't link the stylesheet properly..

Comment: Use Chrome Developer Tools to make sure all resources are loaded properly. Also Inspect the icon element to verify that the styles are correctly applied.

Comment: @Kiliman : I tried that and I don't see any errors in my console or on my network tab.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your link to css file is not correct.

Try to use a full url to your css file:
`<link href="www.yoursite.com/material/vendors/material-icons/material-design-iconic-font.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`
And make sure that url is right by opening it in browser.

Also you need to check your font version, because there is [some changes](http://zavoloklom.github.io/material-design-iconic-font/v1/) in names of css classes since 2.0 was released.